# pytest dependent parameters in parametrize

Tags: python, dependencies, pytest

I would like one parametrize to depend on an earlier one:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("locale_name", LOCALES)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("money_string", ["500{currency}", "500 {currency}"])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("currency", LOCALES['locale_name']['currencies'])
def test_do_stuff(locale_name, money_string, currency):
    print(locale_name, money_string, currency)
```

Here, the 3rd parametrize depends on the first.

I tried to split it up in the following way:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("locale_name", LOCALES)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("money_string", ["500{currency}", "500 {currency}"])
def test_currencies(locale_name, money_string):
    # locale is actually also needed as an object, cannot be taken out. 
    locale = LOCALES[locale_name]

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("currency", locale['currencies'])
    def test_inner_currencies(currency):
        print("this does not run however")
```

But the inner code does not run. I'm not sure what can I do about this case, other than pre-generating the pairs using `itertools.product` (but that would look quite ugly)?

Note that I could just have a for loop, but then I would not "officially" run as many tests.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think py.test supports tests with in tests, If I understand correctly based on your example code, all you want is to test the currencies, Assuming `LOCALES` is a nested dict , I would do something of this sort to address the test

```
import pytest

LOCALES = {"US": {"currencies": "dollar"},
           "EU": {"currencies": "euro"},
           "IN": {"currencies": "rupees"},
           "CH": {"currencies": "yuan"}}

def currencies():
    return [(local_name, currency["currencies"]) for local_name, currency in
            LOCALES.items()]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("currency", currencies())
@pytest.mark.parametrize("money_string", ["500{currency}", "500 {currency}"])
def test_currencies(currency, money_string):
    locale_name, currency = currency
    print locale_name, money_string, currency
```

And the output

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.10, pytest-2.9.2, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /Users/sanjay/Library/Preferences/PyCharm2016.2/scratches, inifile: 
plugins: xdist-1.14
collected 8 items

scratch_11.py EU 500{currency} euro
.CH 500{currency} yuan
.US 500{currency} dollar
.IN 500{currency} rupees
.EU 500 {currency} euro
.CH 500 {currency} yuan
.US 500 {currency} dollar
.IN 500 {currency} rupees
.

=========================== 8 passed in 0.03 seconds ===========================

Process finished with exit code 0
```